# Image Slider not go to next or prev item

Tags: javascript, jquery

(I face a problem when i click on prev chevron the slider works for once and stops after the next click)

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I am trying to build my own slider code. at first when you click on the next chevron the code is working well but when I click on the prev chevron the code is stopped after the second click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentImg = $('.slider-img .active');
    var nextImg = currentImg.next();
    var prevImg = currentImg.prev();

//slide to right
$('.next').on('click', function(){
    if(!currentImg.is(':last-child')){
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        nextImg.addClass('active');
    }else{
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        $('.slider-img div').eq(0).addClass('active');
    }      
});

//Slide to left
$('.prev').on('click', function(){
    if(!currentImg.is(':first-child')){
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        prevtImg.addClass('active');
    }else{
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        $('.slider-img div:last-child').addClass('active');
    }

 });
 });
```

[there is the full code on codepen  bellow](https://codepen.io/mona90/pen/GRgypXZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you declare your variable outside of `click` event, when `document` is `ready` `currentImg` is first element, after you click, `currentImg` need to detect again because right now it's second element, so for avoid this issue, move your `variable` inside your `click` handler:

```
$('.next').on('click', function(){
    var currentImg = $('.slider-img .active');
    var nextImg = currentImg.next();
    var prevImg = currentImg.prev();

    if(!currentImg.is(':last-child')){
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        nextImg.addClass('active');
    }else{
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        $('.slider-img div').eq(0).addClass('active');
    }      
});
```

*An improved version is:*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var firstChild = $('.slider-img div.item').eq(0);
  var lastChild = $('.slider-img div.item:last-child');

  //slide to right
  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    var currentImg = $('.slider-img .active');
    var nextImg = currentImg.next();

    if (!currentImg.is(':last-child')) {
      currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active')
      nextImg.addClass('active')
    } else {
      currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active')
      firstChild.addClass('active');
    }

  });

  //Slide to left
  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    var currentImg = $('.item.active');
    var prevImg = currentImg.prev();

    if (currentImg.is(':first-child')) {
      currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active')
      lastChild.addClass('active')
    } else {
      currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active')
      prevImg.addClass('active');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}

.slider ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

.slider ul li {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider ul li.active {
  background-color: #000;
}

.slider-img div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider-img div.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  color: #cccccc;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider .next {
  right: 0;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: red
}

.item2 {
  background-color: green
}

.item3 {
  background-color: purple
}

.item4 {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></li>
    <li class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></li>
    <li class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></li>
    <li class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="slider-img">
    <div class="item item1 active"></div>
    <div class="item item2"></div>
    <div class="item item3"></div>
    <div class="item item4"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="next">
    >
  </p>
  <p class="prev">
    < </p>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not set the `variable` to the new `value` once the prev or next button is clicked.

That is how it works, even though your approach is a bit complicated:

(Also I recommend to use `let` instead of `var` for your `variable declaration`)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let currentImg = $('.slider-img .active');
    let nextImg = currentImg.next();
    let prevImg = currentImg.prev();

//slide to right
$('.next').on('click', function(){
    if(!currentImg.is(':last-child')){
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        nextImg.addClass('active');
        currentImg = nextImg;
        nextImg = currentImg.next();
    }else{
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        $('.slider-img div').eq(0).addClass('active');
        currentImg = $('.slider-img .active');
        nextImg = currentImg.next();
    }      
});

$('.prev').on('click', function(){
    if(!currentImg.is(':first-child')){
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        prevImg.addClass('active');
        currentImg = prevImg;
        prevImg = currentImg.prev();
    }else{
        currentImg.delay(1000).removeClass('active');
        $('.slider-img div:last-child').addClass('active');
        currentImg = $('.slider-img .active');
        prevImg = currentImg.prev();
    }

 });
 });
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.slider{
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
}
.slider ul{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 3;
}
.slider ul li{
    width:12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider ul li.active{
    background-color: #000;
}
.slider-img div{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.slider-img div.active{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slider-img img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slider p{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    color: #cccccc;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider .next{
    right: 0;
}
.item1{background-color:red}
.item2{background-color:green}
.item3{background-color:purple}
.item4{background-color:yellow}
```

```html
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="slider">
            <ul>
              <li class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></li>
              <li class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></li>
              <li class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></li>
              <li class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></li>
            </ul>
  
             <div class="slider-img">
                  <div class="item item1 active"></div> 
                  <div class="item item2"></div> 
                  <div class="item item3"></div> 
                  <div class="item item4"></div>             </div>  
              <p class="next">
                  <i class="fas fa-chevron-right">next</i>
              </p>
              <p class="prev">
                  <i class="fas fa-chevron-left">prev</i>
              </p>
  
          </section>
```